# Python package won't upgrade

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

As part of a deployment procedure, I upload Python source packages (generated with `setup.py sdist`) to a remote server and install them in a virtualenv using `pip install mypackage-1.0.tar.bz2`.

This has worked for long time both for new installs and upgrades (specifically, upgrades *without* a change in the package's version number). For some reason I cannot figure out, since yesterday, it fails to upgrade the packages. No error is reported, the files are just not changed. Now I'm sure I'm doing something differently but I can't explain the change in behaviour.

I can upgrade the package with the `-U --no-deps` flags, but this technique forces the deployment script to differentiate between first install and upgrades (--no-deps is required as otherwise dependencies would be downloaded each time from pypi).

Any ideas how I can get a single pip command to do installs and upgrades?

Comment: After activating the virtualenv, `pip install mypackage-1.0.tar.bz2` is what used to work, `pip install -U --no-deps mypackage-1.0.tar.bz2` is what now allows me to do an upgrade.

Comment: Then put that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install package` will only be executed with you don't have this package already.
With you want to upgrade the package you'll have to use: `pip install -U package`